# Send analog value over IR?

Tags: robotics, ir, wireless

for my rc robot I want to use ir to send/receive the value from a jostick.

Is it possible ? I can't use any other radio chip like nrf24l01.

Comment: Yes. It's possible.

Comment: documentation ? library? website?

Comment: I don't know any of those. I know it is technically possible though, which is what you asked. Maybe Google knows where the websites are?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. That is already supported by the IR library. Please see this [tutorial](http://garagelab.com/profiles/blogs/tutorial-arduino-ir-sender-and-receiver) for further details. The outline of the sender is:

```
 uint16_t sample = analogRead(A0);
 irsend.sendSony(sample, 16);
```

And the receiver:

```
 if (irrecv.decode(&decodedSignal)) {
    uint16_t sample = decodedSignal.value;
    ...
 }
```

Cheers!